# How are the rewards for Warzone Firefight determined?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

Warzone Firefight is a co-operative game mode where you kill a lot of AI baddies while using reqs like a traditional Warzone game. I've played several games in this new mode, and it's quite fun.

My question stems from the fact that I've received significantly different rewards from my several games. I've received anywhere from 4(!) gold(!!) req packs after a match to... nothing.

My initial thought was that a player's ending score influenced the rewards they got, perhaps combined with whether their team succeeded or not... but my recent game saw my team wining and me racking up a whopping 37k points to receive no rewards whatsoever.

How are these rewards determined?

Comment: I haven't played enough of the official release to get an accurate result, but during the beta. The amount of REQs you *used* played a role in how much REQ points you earned, as well as the usual suspects. rank on the board, score, time played, kills, etc.

Comment: Ah, so using fewer reqs would yield higher rewards? Or vice-versa?

Comment: vice versa. I think all warzone modes work that way, to help prevent the player from depleting their REQ supply.

Answer (score 3):

Warzone firefight commendations now award gold packs. There is also a bonus system for victories.

1st win: 1 gold pack
5th win: 3 gold packs
10th win: 5 gold packs

Answer (score 0):

You get rewards in Warzone Firefight when unlocking commendations like @two bugs pointed. In addition to getting packs from winning firefight matches you get them also from killing prometheans, covenants and bosses separately.